# WinSCP - Do not synchronize subdirectories

Tags: winscp

I am writing winscp script in VBA to synchronize certain files from remote to local.
The code I am using is

```
""synchronize -filemask=""""*.xlsx"""" local C:\Users\xx\Desktop /JrnlDetailSFTPDirect""
```

There are three xlsx files: 14.xlsx, 12.xlsx, 13.xlsx. However, seems like it is running through all the files even though it is not synchronizing them. Besides, one folder under `JrnlDetailSFTPDirect` is also downloaded from remote, which is not expected.[image]

Is it possible to avoid looping through all the files, just selecting those three files and downloading them?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [separate masks for files and folders](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask).

To exclude all folders, use `*/` exclude mask:

```
synchronize -filemask="*.xlsx|*/" local C:\Users\xx\Desktop /JrnlDetailSFTPDirect
```

See [How do I transfer (or synchronize) directory non-recursively?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_non_recursive)

---

I cannot tell anything regarding the other problem, as you didn't show us names of the files. Ideally, append a session log file to your question. Use [`/log` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#logging) like:

```
winscp.com /log=c:\writablepath\winscp.log /command ...
```